# Trying again after a urllib2.URLError: <urlopen error [Errno 111] Connection refused>

Tags: python-2.7, exception

Is this code correct?  I ended up getting an Errno 111 and the program still quit rather than trying again and again.

When i get a connection error, i want to wait 10 seconds and then retry to get the URL again.

I'm using Python 2.7.

```
import errno
for attempt in range(20):
    try:
        browser.get(url)
    except EnvironmentError as exc:
        if exc.errno == errno.ECONNREFUSED:
            anow = datetime.datetime.now()
            print("got a 111 connection error",anow)
            time.sleep(10)
        elif exc.errno == errno.ECONNRESET:
            anow = datetime.datetime.now()
            print("got a RESET connection error",anow)
            time.sleep(10)
        else:
            continue
    else:
        break
else:
    print("tried 20 times - kept getting Error")
```

Comment: Is the 111 somehow related to you code? Did you make sure that people who want to help you don't have to look up stuff that you can provide in you question?

Answer (score 0):

So this is what I ended up doing, and it seems to work:

What I wanted was something that would re-try again after any error, but also tell me what the error was. This code is running on PythonANywhere so i am not worried about keyboard interrupts, etc...  Besides, the attempt in `range()` ensures that the code doesn't run forever as it would in a While-True loop.

```
for attempt in range(1,3):
     try:
         browser.get(url)
         print("browser success",i)
         break
     except Exception as e:
         print(e," Attempt:" + str(attempt))
         time.sleep(4)
         pass
```